# Get / Calculate edges of a 3D object - C #

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, geometry

I need to get all vertices in the edge position of a determinate object 3D (in this case a path).

See the image:

[image]

My question is, how can I get only the edges vertices, like the image?

Comment: I'm a little confused what defines an edge.  You have a 2D projection of a 3D object here.  Aren't all the vertices edge vertices in 3D?  Are you asking for the vertices in the case of a particular 2D project?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to iterate over all your triangle faces tallying up a count of each edge.

Any internal edge is shared by two faces, any external edge will appear only once.